# Create input fields based on a recursive form of key-value pairs in Angular 7+

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a formArray that will contain Key-value pairs to display in the template as a label and an input field.

After following a couple of articles (and my error console), this is what I've got so far, but to no result:

**component.ts**

```
foodFormArray = new FormArray([]);
...
this.foodFormArray.push(new FormGroup({"foodName" : new FormControl("Pizza"), "foodOrigin": new FormControl("Italy")}));  
this.foodFormArray.push(new FormGroup({"foodName" : new FormControl("Pho"), "foodOrigin": new FormControl("Vietnam")}));  
this.foodFormArray.push(new FormGroup({"foodName" : new FormControl("Raclette"), "foodOrigin": new FormControl("France")})
```

***template***

```
<div *ngFor="let control of foodFormArray.controls; index as i">
 <div [formGroup]="control">
  <input [formControlName]="foodName" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have it with a real `ng-template` this is how to process.

Create a loop that call your template, with the `*ngTemplateOutlet` and pass the cojntroller & the index to it.
app.component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let foodForm of foodForms">
  <ng-content
    *ngTemplateOutlet="
      nameOfYourTemplate;
      context: {
        attributes: foodForm,
        controlIndex: i
      }
    "
  ></ng-content>
</ng-container>

<!-- The template : can be used for recursive, just call the template into it's own -->
<ng-template #nameOfYourTemplate let-i="attributes" let-controlIndex="controlIndex">
  <div [formGroup]="itemForm">
    <ng-container formArrayName="foodFormArray">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="controlIndex">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>{{ i.title }}</mat-label>
          <input [name]="i.id" [formControlName]="i.id" matInput />
        </mat-form-field>
      <!-- here, add <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="nameOfYourTemplate;" if you want a real recursive function -->
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Then, I would recommend creating a fromGroup, I think, there are your misunderstanding. cause your did try to use `control` for `[formGroup]` but `control` should have been user with `formArrayName`
app.component.ts

```js
   itemForm = new FormGroup({})
  
  constructor(protected _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.itemForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      foodForms = new FormArray([]),
    })
  }
```

I didn't test the code but it should work or at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this, @Raphael :)

this is what ended up working for me

in the component.ts
`worldFoodForms: FormArray = this.fb.array([ this.fb.group({"foodName" : this.fb.control("Pizza"), "foodOrigin": this.fb.control("Italy")}), this.fb.group({"foodName" : this.fb.control("Pho"), "foodOrigin": this.fb.control("Vietnam")}) ]);`

and in the template.html
`<div *ngFor="let control of singleValueFieldsForm.controls; index as i "> <strong>{{control.controls.key.value}}</strong> <input [formControl]="control.controls.value"></div>`